# Android Kotlin MVVM with dagger, JetPack components

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, dagger-2, android-jetpack

Currently i am working in Kotlin android development. while writing the MVVM architecture, i am stuck with ViewModel Creation
Error : Only classes are allowed on the left hand side of a class literal

Related classes are

Detail

BaseViewModel class, while creating the object of this class, we getting the error

```
package com.logicipher.mvvm.ui.base

import androidx.databinding.ObservableBoolean
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import com.logicipher.mvvm.data.DataManager
import com.logicipher.mvvm.utils.rx.SchedulerProvider
import io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference

/**
 * Created by Shamji N S on 20-08-2020.
 */
abstract class BaseViewModel<N>(
    dataManager: DataManager,
    schedulerProvider: SchedulerProvider
) : ViewModel() {
    private val mDataManager: DataManager
    private val mIsLoading = ObservableBoolean()
    private val mSchedulerProvider: SchedulerProvider
    private val mCompositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable
    private var mNavigator: WeakReference<N>? = null
    override fun onCleared() {
        mCompositeDisposable.dispose()
        super.onCleared()
    }

    fun getCompositeDisposable(): CompositeDisposable {
        return mCompositeDisposable
    }

    fun getDataManager(): DataManager {
        return mDataManager
    }

    fun getIsLoading(): ObservableBoolean {
        return mIsLoading
    }

    fun setIsLoading(isLoading: Boolean) {
        mIsLoading.set(isLoading)
    }

    fun getNavigator(): N? {
        return mNavigator!!.get()
    }

    fun setNavigator(navigator: N) {
        mNavigator = WeakReference(navigator)
    }

    fun getSchedulerProvider(): SchedulerProvider {
        return mSchedulerProvider
    }

    init {
        mDataManager = dataManager
        mSchedulerProvider = schedulerProvider
        mCompositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
    }
}
```

BaseActivity

```
package com.logicipher.mvvm.ui.base

import android.annotation.TargetApi
import android.app.ProgressDialog
import android.content.Context
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager
import androidx.annotation.LayoutRes
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding
import com.logicipher.mvvm.utils.CommonUtils
import com.logicipher.mvvm.utils.NetworkUtils
import dagger.android.AndroidInjection

/**
 * Created by Shamji N S on 20-08-2020.
 */

abstract class BaseActivity<T : ViewDataBinding?, V : BaseViewModel<*>?> :
    AppCompatActivity(), BaseFragment.Callback {
    // TODO
    // this can probably depend on isLoading variable of BaseViewModel,
    // since its going to be common for all the activities
    private var mProgressDialog: ProgressDialog? = null
    private var mViewDataBinding: T? = null
    private var mViewModel: V? = null

    /**
     * Override for set binding variable
     *
     * @return variable id
     */
    abstract fun getBindingVariable(): Int

    /**
     * @return layout resource id
     */
    @LayoutRes
    abstract fun getLayoutId(): Int

    /**
     * Override for set view model
     *
     * @return view model instance
     */
    abstract fun getViewModel(): V

    override fun onFragmentAttached() {

    }


    override fun onFragmentDetached(tag: String?) {

    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        performDependencyInjection()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        performDataBinding()
    }

    fun getViewDataBinding(): T? {
        return mViewDataBinding
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    fun hasPermission(permission: String?): Boolean {
        return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M ||
                checkSelfPermission(permission!!) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    fun hideKeyboard() {
        val view = this.currentFocus
        if (view != null) {
            val imm =
                getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
            imm?.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
        }
    }

    fun hideLoading() {
        if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog!!.isShowing) {
            mProgressDialog!!.cancel()
        }
    }

    fun isNetworkConnected(): Boolean {
        return NetworkUtils.isNetworkConnected(applicationContext)
    }

    fun openActivityOnTokenExpire() {

    }

    fun performDependencyInjection() {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    fun requestPermissionsSafely(
        permissions: Array<String?>?,
        requestCode: Int
    ) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(permissions!!, requestCode)
        }
    }

    fun showLoading() {
        hideLoading()
        mProgressDialog = CommonUtils.showLoadingDialog(this)
    }

    private fun performDataBinding() {
        mViewDataBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<T>(this, getLayoutId())
        mViewModel = if (mViewModel == null) getViewModel() else mViewModel
        mViewDataBinding!!.setVariable(getBindingVariable(), mViewModel)
        mViewDataBinding!!.executePendingBindings()
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
package com.logicipher.mvvm.ui.main
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
import com.logicipher.mvvm.BR
import com.logicipher.mvvm.R
import com.logicipher.mvvm.ViewModelProviderFactory
import com.logicipher.mvvm.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.logicipher.mvvm.ui.base.BaseActivity
import javax.inject.Inject

/**
 * Created by Shamji N S on 21-08-2020.
 */
class MainActivity : BaseActivity<ActivityMainBinding?, MainViewModel<MainNavigator>?>(),
    MainNavigator /*, HasSupportFragmentInjector*/ {
    /*   @Inject
    DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment> fragmentDispatchingAndroidInjector;*/

    @set:Inject
    internal var factory: ViewModelProviderFactory? = null
    var mViewModel: MainViewModel<MainNavigator>? = null
    var mBinding: ActivityMainBinding? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: ")
        mBinding = getViewDataBinding()
        mViewModel?.setNavigator(this)
    }

    override fun getBindingVariable(): Int {
        return BR.viewModel
    }

    override fun getLayoutId(): Int {
        return R.layout.activity_main
    }

    override fun getViewModel(): MainViewModel<MainNavigator>? {
        mViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get<MainViewModel<MainNavigator>>(MainViewModel<MainNavigator>::class.java)
        return mViewModel
    }

    /*
    @Override
    public AndroidInjector<Fragment> supportFragmentInjector() {
        return fragmentDispatchingAndroidInjector;
    }
*/

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "MainActivity"
    }
}
```

ViewModelProviderFactory

```
package com.logicipher.mvvm

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory
import com.logicipher.mvvm.data.DataManager
import com.logicipher.mvvm.ui.main.MainNavigator
import com.logicipher.mvvm.ui.main.MainViewModel
import com.logicipher.mvvm.utils.rx.SchedulerProvider
import java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
import javax.inject.Inject

/**
 * Created by Shamji N S on 25-08-2020.
 */
public class ViewModelProviderFactory @Inject constructor(
    dataManager: DataManager,
    schedulerProvider: SchedulerProvider
) : NewInstanceFactory() {
    private val dataManager: DataManager
    private val schedulerProvider: SchedulerProvider



    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return super.create(modelClass)

        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(MainViewModel::class.java)) {
            return MainViewModel<T>(dataManager, schedulerProvider) as T
        }

        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown view model" + modelClass.name)
    }

    init {
        this.dataManager = dataManager
        this.schedulerProvider = schedulerProvider
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `BaseViewModel` is abstract, you cannot create an object or an instance of an abstract class.
After you create a `ViewModelFactory` the way to create (or obtain) an instance of the `ViewModel` is this:

`val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(ViewModelName::class.java)`

However, I would consider using `Kotlin Property Delegate` [from here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#implement) which can help reduce the code.

Comment: i am already using this type of representation,




override fun getViewModel(): MainViewModel<MainNavigator>? {



        mViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get<MainViewModel<MainNavigator>>(MainViewModel<MainNavigator>::class.java)
        return mViewModel
    }